# Cygwin, via SSH, is missing a system variables

Tags: ruby, cygwin

A bunch of system variables are missing in Cygwin when using ssh.  Some that I noticed include:

- A proper PATH including the Visual Studio paths.
- VS80COMNTOOLS
- TEMP
- TMP
- PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
- PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER
- PROCESSOR_LEVEL
- PROCESSOR_REVISION
- FP_NO_HOST_CHECK
- PSMODULEPATH

This impacts trying to compile source, such as ruby, via ssh.  These variables exist when using rdesktop.

How do I get these variables to exist in Cygwin when using ssh?

Comment: I added an explicit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a post describing how to work around this: http://smithii.com/node/44

Here is the bit 'o bash from that page:

```
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
pushd . >/dev/null
for __dir in \
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session\ Manager/Environment \
/proc/registry/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment
do
    cd "$__dir"
    for __var in $(ls -1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
    do
        test -z "${!__var}" && export $__var="`cat $__var`" >/dev/null 2>&1
    done
done
unset __dir
unset __var
popd >/dev/null
fi
```

**edited**: Moved the `tr` so it is only done once. It was painfully slow otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the 1 answer here, >=BASH-4.4 will throw warnings about:

```
/etc/profile: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

To fix this, simply change the 'test' line from:

```
test -z "${!__var}" && export $__var="`cat $__var`" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to:

```
test -z "${!__var}" && export $__var="`cat $__var | tr -d '\0'`" >/dev/null 2>&1
```